# Evaluating $\lim_{x→\pi^{-}}$ $\ln(\sin x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I was wondering, if I wanted to evaluate ; $$\displaystyle\lim_{x→\pi^{-}}\ln(\sin x)$$

Would there be anyway of doing it other than calculating successively values that are near $\pi $?

Comment: I think the notation used means as $x$ approaches pi from the left.

Comment: As x approaches pi from the negative side

Comment: What, that's not the notation you use ?

Comment: @Astroman: That is the notation that I am used to.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to \pi -}\ln (\sin x)=\lim_{t\to 0+}\ln t=-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to \pi^-$, $\sin x\to 0^+$. Thus, 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\ln(\sin x)=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to\pi^-}\sin x\right)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\ln t=-\infty.$$

If it helps you, you could confirm it graphically:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. $\sin x$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ with and an image  of $[0,1]$, and $\ln$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.  So, $\lim_{x\to\pi^-}\ln(\sin x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln x=-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin x$ you're trying to find
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \ln(\sin x)$$
As $x$ goes to zero from above, $\sin(x)$ goes to zero from above, so $\ln(\sin x)$ goes to $-\infty$.

Another way to see the same thing: $\sin x = {\sin x \over x} x$, so the limit is
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \ln\bigg({\sin x \over x}\bigg)+ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \ln x$$
Since ${\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} {\sin x \over x} = 1}$, the first term goes to $\ln 1 = 0$. So the overall limit is the limit of the second term, given by $-\infty$.